# Передача данных URL-JSON

Tags: php, javascript, массивы, json, url

Наткнулся на такую задачку.

Есть файл с массивом ***`array()`***;

> **ПРМЕР:**

```
array(
  "TICKET"=> array(
    "BTC"=>array(
       "USD"=>array(
          "price"=>"6975",
          "low"=>"6320",
          "high"=>"7101"
       ),
       "RUB"=>array(
          "price"=>"459671",
          "low"=>"430522",
          "high"=>"486197"
       ),
    ),
    "LTC"=>array(
       "USB"=>array(
          "price"=>"671",
          "low"=>"640",
          "high"=>"692"
       ),
       "RUB"=>array(
          "price"=>"459671",
          "low"=>"430522",
          "high"=>"486197"
       ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Нужно реализовать ссылку такими образом чтобы она выводила на страницу только определённую валютную пару.

> **ПРИМЕР ССЫЛКИ :** https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd

Где **`btc-usd`** это валютная пара.
И при переходе на данную ссылку на странице выводится именно информация об этой валютной паре.

> Пример вывода информации на странице можно посмотреть [**тут**](https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd)

ПРИМЕР НА КАРТИНКЕ

> [image]

И того, как же мне реализовать такую ссылку и каким образом, пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: Я ничего не знаю про веб, но думаю, что это ссылка ненастоящая должна быть, а типа сокращенная и более понятная на вид. На деле же там какой-то php скрипт который получает btc-usd как аргумент

Comment: `mod_rewrite` апача вам в руки, если апачи, или аналоги на других серверах. Составляете правило переопределения запроса, так чтобы нужный параметр передавался в скрипт. ну а дальше инклуд файла и извлечение нужных данных